# prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n}=$finite

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Given that $(a_n)_{n\to\infty}$ satisfies the condition $\vert a_n-a_{n+1}\vert <\frac{1}{4^n}$ $\forall n\in\mathbb N$ prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n={}$finite
I wanted to prove that using Cauchy's convergence test. I need to show that $\vert a_{m}-a_{n}\vert <\epsilon\quad\forall m,n\in\mathbb N$. $\quad$ So that's what I did: Let assume without loss of generallity that $m>n$ than

\begin{align}
& \vert a_m-a_n\vert=\vert a_m-a_{m-1}+a_{m-1}+\cdots-a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}-a_n\vert
\\[10pt]
\le {} & \vert a_m-a_{m-1}\vert + \vert a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}\vert+\cdots+\vert a_{n+1}-a_n\vert
\\[10pt]
< {} &\frac{1}{4^m}+\frac{1}{4^{m-1}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}
<\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^n}<\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon
\end{align}

So I proved it eusing Cauchy's convergence test but Im not sure that I can say for sure that $\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^n}<\frac{n}{n^2}$ because when I said that I assumed that there is only $n$ terms in the left equation, but what if there is more? I can't know for sure, or maybe because $n\to \infty$ it donsn't relly matter so what I'm asking basically that if my proof holds?

Comment: Is your Cauchy condition correct?

Comment: If by Cauchy condition you mean $\vert a_{m}-a_{n}\vert<\epsilon$ so yes this is correct

Comment: @needhelp I think tommy may have meant that $$|a_m-a_{m-1}|<\frac1{4^{\color{red}m}}\;,\;\;\text{and etc...for example...}$$

Comment: Oh ,yeah I need to add that $m>n$ than it means that $\frac{1}{4^m}<\frac{1}{4^n}$

Comment: You've bounded all your terms by the same value (i.e. $1/4^n$), and that's not going to work, because, as you noticed, you can get an arbitrarily large number of terms. Notice that as you go from the $n$th to the $(n+1)$th to the $(n+2)$th difference, you can bound them by $1/4^{n}$, $1/4^{n+1}$, $1/4^{n+2}$, and so on. Can you use this to show that with this change you no longer care how many terms you get?

Comment: Yeah,I can use the formula for the sum of the geomtric series. thank you